# Lost on screen player help when reaching rank 25

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I'm a horrible shot and also have a hard time determining the difference of friend and foe. I relied heavily on the on-screen info that I was given when my cross hair passed over a player, showing blue (friend) and red (foe). Now that I reached the rank of 25, that seems to have gone away. Is this just a way of making the game harder as you rank up? Have I lost that benefit for good? Maybe I need a new set of glasses.

Comment: not sure why, but it seems to be back, must be a glitch.

Comment: Is this on the Xbox One? I've been looking around the forums, and it seems that this is a known bug. Xbox users seem to be able to temporarily fix the issue by either force-quitting the game (Home Screen -> Start -> Quit), or restarting the console. It doesn't look like any permanent solution has been found yet.

Comment: yes, xbox one, and I haven't had the issue again.

Answer (score 1):

I am Level 58 and my crosshair still works as normal. Leveling up only gives you access to more skins, weapons, and emotes, nothing else. You must have a bug in your game.